# How to loop records through textfield value

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

I'm thinking how can I loop my records through textfield if the user hit the **Edit** button. I have ***search*** blade template where the list of records has put in the table data.

search.blade.php

```
<table class = "table">
<br>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Middlename</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>

</thead>


<tbody>
@foreach ($data as $row)
    <tr class = "success">
        <td>{{ $row->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->middle_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->username }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href = "{{ route ('account.edit', $row->id) }}"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-warning">Edit</button></a>
            <a href = "#"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger">Archive</button></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

I loop also the `id` of the **Users** table in my `account.edit` view so it will know which id is selected.

Routes:

```
//READ
Route::get('/search',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@getEmployee',
    'as' => 'account.search',
]);


//EDIT
Route::get('/edit/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@editEmployee',
    'as' => 'account.edit',
]);
```

Controller:

```
//READ
public function getEmployee()
{
    $result = DB::table('users')->get();

    return view ('account.search')->with('data', $result);
}


//EDIT
public function editEmployee($id)
{
    $result = User::find($id);

    return view ('account.edit')->with('data', $result);
}
```

This part where I stuck still do not have a idea where I'm gonna loop each table attributes in my ***edit*** blade template unfortunately it gives me a error.

> Missing required parameters for [Route: account.edit] [URI: edit/{id}]. (View: C:\Users\JohnFrancis\LaravelFrancis\resources\views\account\edit.blade.php)

```
<form class = "form-vertical" role = "form" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('account.edit') }}">

<h3>Edit Employee</h3>
<hr>

<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "email" class = "control-label">Email Address</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "email" class = "form-control" value = "{{ $result->email }}">

</div>

<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "username" class = "control-label">Username</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "username" class = "form-control" value = "{{ $result->username }}">

</div>

<div class = "form-group">

    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success">Save</button> 

</div>

<input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "{{ $result->id }}">
<input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you missed an id paraveter at this part
`action = "{{ route ('account.edit') }}"`
It should be like this
`action = "{{ route ('account.edit', $result->id) }}"`

Comment: It says `Undefined variable: result`. I think I need to loop inside my form statement.

Comment: Try using `$data` since you're passing `$result` through that.